# Firefox crashes with segv fault when started

Tags: systemd, firefox

I am working on a yocto image based on the Kirkstone branch and want to include a Firefox Browser running on Wayland which autostarts at boot.

I have build an image including Firefox and a systemd service file to autostart it when my system boots (raspberry PI 4 Compute module with DSI touchscreen).

The system has a `user=weston` present which is autoconfigured in a yocto build when you build with wayland support.. This user also has the Wayland display.
Furthermore I have one other configured user: `user=service` which I mainly use to debug.

What I try to do is to boot firefox via systemd using the following systemd file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start a wayland application
After=weston.service
Requires=weston.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=weston
Group=weston
PAMName=login
Environment=WAYLAND_DISPLAY=/run/user/1000/wayland-1
Environment=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
Environment=MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/firefox

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

However at boot the browser doesn't start and systemd reports a crash:

```
Jan 15 22:38:18 hometerminal-cm4 systemd[1]: Started Start a firefox browser.
-- Subject: A start job for unit firefox.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- A start job for unit firefox.service has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 1089.
Jan 15 22:38:21 hometerminal-cm4 systemd[1]: firefox.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit firefox.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'killed' and its exit status is 11.
Jan 15 22:38:21 hometerminal-cm4 systemd[1]: firefox.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- The unit firefox.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'signal'.
```

Which would state that I have a segv fault, I just don't understand why? I am guessing it has something to do with the environment in which the system runs.

I have made a similar systemd file for testing which I use to run weston-terminal at boot and that works fine. It is fully identical to the above except for the `Execstart` and the `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` not being there.

How do you configure the environment for a firefox browser in such a way that it can autostart at boot?

Comment: The problem might be related to running Firefox as root. I think you should use a systemd user service or change `User=root` to your current  user (create it if you only have the root user)

Comment: You are correct, I have now reworked my image so that the root user is no longer present as seen in the edited original question.

Comment: Show the output of: `sudo journalctl -xeu your_service.service`. That may show a more detailed log about the current error.

Comment: I have added the output as requested.

Comment: If you run the service directly: `sudo systemctl start yourservice`, do you have the same error?

Comment: Yes, I have the same error unfortunately.

Comment: If you try with another browser, does the service work? Maybe it's a firefox bug (in my case I was able to run firefox with your systemd service and it worked correctly). I only had to change `WAYLAND_DISPLAY=/run/user/1000/wayland-1` to `WAYLAND_DISPLAY=/run/user/1000/wayland-0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. There was an error somewhere in firefox which causes runtime segv error when running. Using the above systemd script but replacing firefox with chromium works like a charm.